# jQuery: sequential numbering control

Tags: jquery, sorting, sequence, html-select

Is there any plugin for changing the sequential numbering of items inside a table when selecting a new sequence using a dropdown list?

e.g.

Before changing sorting id

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| AAA | ... | ... |  1  |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| BBB | ... | ... |  3  | < I like to change this sequence id to 2 using DropDown
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| CCC | ... | ... |  2  |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

After selecting sequence it should looks like

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| AAA | ... | ... |  1  |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| BBB | ... | ... |  2  |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| CCC | ... | ... |  3  |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

CCC should be updated automatically

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You probably need a function that loops through each table row and sets the 'order number' to be sequential. Every time the order changes you run the function:

Using jquery(there are other ways/libaries available)e.g.

```
function set_sequence(){
var count = 0
$("table tr").each(function(){
        count++;
        $(this).attr(id) = count; //or
        $(this).find('td.order').text(count);

    }); 
}
```

This is untested but hopefully you get the idea.